# Should I unescape bytea field in C-function for Postgresql and if so - how to do it?

Tags: c, postgresql, bytea

I write my own C function for Postgresql which have bytea parameter. This function is defined as followed

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION putDoc(entity_type int, entity_id int, 
        doc_type text, doc_data bytea) RETURNS text
     AS 'proj_pg', 'call_putDoc'
     LANGUAGE C STRICT;
```

My function `call_putDoc`, written on C, reads `doc_data` and pass its data to another function like `file_magic` to determine mime-type of the data and then pass data to appropriate file converter.

I call this postgresql function from php script which loads file content to last parameter. So, I should pass file contents with `pg_escape_bytea`.

When data are passed to `call_putDoc` C function, does its data already unescaped and if not - how to unescape them?

**Edit:** As I found, no, data, passed to C function, is not unescaped. How to unescape it?

Comment: As far, as nobody answers, seems I found a "solution", which doesn't answer the question.
To pass data to DB we can use base64_encode. When pass data in C function we can use GLib g_base64_decode function.

But this solution is not really good - size of stored data becomes very huge... So, answer is still actual.

Comment: And as I can see while debugging, yes - I must unescape passed data. But how?

Comment: No, don't use GLib functions. Use Pg's built-in bytea handling functions, they're aware of the `bytea_encoding` so they'll work with both `hex` and `octal` format data.

Comment: But I cann't found that bytea handling functions. Where can I found them?

Comment: `src/include/utils/bytea.h` and `src/backend/util/adt/varlena.c`

Comment: BTW, you *MUST* show your PostgreSQL version for questions like this.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that, postgresql 8.4

Comment: OK, so that's before the advent of the `bytea_output=hex` GUC default change, when it still defaulted to `escape`, which uses octal escapes (see the link in my answer). Newer versions use `hex`. No version uses, or can use, `base64` so if you're getting `base64` data that's because you're passing a `bytea` full of `base64` encoded data.

Comment: No, it was a quick-dirty fix to check all other works good. Currently, I use pg_escape_bytea PHP function to escape argument.

Comment: OK, I've written a pretty detailed explanation in that answer (just updated), including showing how to [attach a debugger to a backend and set a breakpoint](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Generating_a_stack_trace_of_a_PostgreSQL_backend) to confirm behaviour. That should help you out. If you don't know how to use `gdb`, now's a great time to learn, it's a great tool.

Comment: OK, then you need to verify that what I've said below still applies on the old Pg 8.4. Try setting a breakpoint like I showed, make sure `byteain` is being called to unescape before your func gets called. If it is, delete the breakpoint and add another one in your code, then step through it and use the `gdb` `print` command to look at variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When it comes to programming C functions for PostgreSQL, the documentation explains some of the basics, but for the rest it's usually down to reading the source code for the PostgreSQL server.

Thankfully the code is usually well structured and easy to read. I wish it had more doc comments though.

Some vital tools for navigating the source code are either:

- A good IDE; or
- The `find` and `git grep` commands.

In this case, after having a look I think your `bytea` argument *is* being decoded - at least in Pg 9.2, it's possible (though rather unlikely) that 8.4 behaved differently. The server should automatically do that before calling your function, and I suspect you have a programming error in how you are calling your `putDoc` function from SQL. Without sources it's hard to say more.

- Try calling it `putDoc` from `psql` with some sample data you've verified is correctly `escape` encoded for your 8.4 server
- Try setting a breakpoint in `byteain` to make sure it's called before your function
- Follow through the steps below to verify that what I've said applies to 8.4.
- Set a breakpoint in your function and step through with `gdb`, using the `print` function as you go to examine the variables. There are lots of gdb tutorials that'll teach you the required `break`, `backtrace`, `cont`, `step`, `next`, `print`, etc commands, so I won't repeat all that here.

As for what's wrong: You could be double-encoding your data - for example, given your comments I'm wondering if you've `base64` encoded data and passed it to `Pg` with `bytea_output` set to `escape`. Pg would then decode it ... giving you a `bytea` containing the `bytea` representation of the `base64` encoding of the bytes, not the raw bytes themselves. (**Edit** Sounds like probably not based on comments).

For correct use of `bytea` see:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html

To say more I'd need source code.

Here's what I did:

---

A quick `find -name bytea\*` in the source tree locates `src/include/utils/bytea.h`. A comment there notes that the function definitions are in `utils/adt/varlena.c` - which turns out to actually be `src/backend/util/adt/varlena.c`.

In `bytea.h` you'll also notice the definition of the `bytea_output` GUC parameter, which is what you see when you `SHOW bytea_output` or `SET bytea_output` in `psql`.

Let's have a look at a function we know does something with `bytea` data, like `bytea_substr`, in `varlena.c`. It's so short I'll include one of its declarations here:

```c
Datum
bytea_substr(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
        PG_RETURN_BYTEA_P(bytea_substring(PG_GETARG_DATUM(0),
                    PG_GETARG_INT32(1),
                    PG_GETARG_INT32(2),
                    false));
}
```

Many of the public functions are wrappers around private implementation, so the private implementation can be re-used with functions that have differing arguments, or from other private code too. This is such a case; you'll see that the real implementation is `bytea_substring`. All the above does is handle the SQL function calling interface. It doesn't mess with the `Datum` containing the `bytea` input at all.

The real implementation `bytea_substring` follows directly below the SQL interface wrappers in this partcular case, so read on in `varlena.c`.

The implementation doesn't seem to refer to the `bytea_output` GUC, and basically just calls `DatumGetByteaPSlice` to do the work after handling some border cases. `git grep DatumGetByteaPSlice` shows us that `DatumGetByteaPSlice` is in `src/include/fmgr.h`, and is a macro defined as:

```c
#define DatumGetByteaPSlice(X,m,n)      ((bytea *) PG_DETOAST_DATUM_SLICE(X,m,n))
```

where `PG_DETOAST_DATUM_SLICE` is

```c
#define PG_DETOAST_DATUM_SLICE(datum,f,c) \
            pg_detoast_datum_slice((struct varlena *) DatumGetPointer(datum), \
            (int32) (f), (int32) (c))
```

so it's just detoasting the datum and returning a memory slice. This leaves me wondering: has the decoding been done elsewhere, as part of the function call interface? Or have I missed something?

A look at `byteain`, the input function for `bytea`, shows that it's certainly decoding the data. Set a breakpoint in that function and it should trip when you call your function from SQL, showing that the `bytea` data is really being decoded.

For example, let's see if `byteain` gets called when we call `bytea_substr` with:

```sql
SELECT substring('1234'::bytea, 2,2);
```

In case you're wondering how `substring(bytea)` gets turned into a `C` call to `bytea_substr`, look at `src/catalog/pg_proc.h` for the mappings.

We'll start psql and get the pid of the backend:

```
$ psql -q regress
regress=# select pg_backend_pid();
 pg_backend_pid 
----------------
          18582
(1 row)
```

then in another terminal connect to that pid with gdb, set a breakpoint, and continue execution:

```
$ sudo -u postgres gdb -q -p 18582
Attaching to process 18582
... blah blah ...
(gdb) break bytea_substr
Breakpoint 1 at 0x6a9e40: file varlena.c, line 1845.
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
```

In the 1st terminal we execute in psql:

```sql
SELECT substring('1234'::bytea, 2,2);
```

... and notice that it hangs without returning a result. Good. That's because we tripped the breakpoint in gdb, as you can see in the 2nd terminal:

```
Breakpoint 1, bytea_substr (fcinfo=0x1265690) at varlena.c:1845
1845            PG_RETURN_BYTEA_P(bytea_substring(PG_GETARG_DATUM(0),
(gdb)
```

A backtrace with the `bt` command doesn't show `bytea_substr` in the call path, it's all SQL function call machinery. So Pg is decoding the `bytea` before it's passing it to `bytea_substr`.

You can now detach the debugger with `quit`. This won't quit the Pg backend, only detach and quit the debugger.